# Function that changes all lower case letters to uppercase

Tags: python, function

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def uppercase(str):
    new = ''
    for i in str:
        if (ord(i) > 96 and ord(i) < 123):
            new = new + chr(ord(i) - 32)
print("{}".format(new))
```

This is my code, but it does not work. I am new to python, and why is my code not working?

Comment: Doing `new =` inside the function doesn't change anything outside the function.  You probably want to `return new`  at the end of your function.  You also need to actually call the function if you want it to do anything.  You also probably don't want to name the parameter `str` since that's the name of the string type in Python (if you give something else that name, it's very confusing and might cause bugs if you try to use the real `str` elsewhere in your code).

Comment: Use `str.upper()`, ex. `print("this is uppercase".upper())`

Comment: Try to avoid the built-in *str* as your variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in method upper()
Try this:

```py
foo = "hello, world!"
print(foo.upper())
```

This will uppercase the letters for you (you can use it directly on strings like this):

```py
print("Hello, world!".upper())
```

If you want to make it by yourself (which is fine to learn) you should use a return statement

```py
def uppercase(msg):
    new = ''
    for i in msg:
        if (ord(i) > 96 and ord(i) < 123):
            new = new + chr(ord(i) - 32)
    return new

print("{}".format(uppercase("Hello, world!")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code by

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def uppercase(str):
    new = ''
    for i in str:
        if (ord(i) > 96 and ord(i) < 123):
            new = new + chr(ord(i) - 32)
    return new

print("{}".format(uppercase('SomeThing')))
```

or use the function `upper()`

```
message = 'python is fun'

# convert message to uppercase
print(message.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem *with your code* is that (a) you need to call your function `uppercase`, like this:

```
print(uppercase('Hello, world!"))
```

And second, you only copy characters that need to be uppercased (i.e. the lower case letters). Any other character should be copied unchanged.